# PHP static method recursive

Tags: php, recursion, methods, static

Is it possible to do a recursion on a static method?

```
    class Helpers {
         public static function objectToArray($obj) {
            if (is_object($obj)) {
                $obj = get_object_vars($obj);
            }

            if (is_array($obj)) {
                return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $obj);
            }
            else {
                return $obj;
            }
         }
    }
```

I'm getting this error when executed:

Severity: Warning

Message: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'objectToArray' not found or invalid function name.

Thanks!

Comment: When specifying an object or class callback you have to use `"self::funcName"` or `array("self",__FUNCTION__)` instead of a plain function name string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
return array_map(['Helpers', 'objectToArray'], $obj);
```

array_map permit [`callable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) type.

You could try it with [magic constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

```
return array_map([__CLASS__, __METHOD__], $obj);
```

Or using `self`

```
return array_map([self, __METHOD__], $obj);
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for this!!! I think using magic constants is the best answer especially when the class or method name is updated. There will be no need to edit the return line as it will automatically get the name of the class and the method itself.

Comment: Instead of `[__CLASS__, __METHOD__]` you can also just use  `__METHOD__`: `return array_map(__METHOD__, $obj);`

Answer (score 7):

You can recursively call a static method. The
following code, for example, will work fine:

```
<?php 

class MyClass{
    public static function test($count)
    {       
        if ($count < 10) {
            $count++;
            self::test($count);
            
            echo $count;                
        }
    }
}

MyClass::test(0);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for the OP title of the question

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
return array_map('self::objectToArray', $obj);
```

// or

```
return array_map(array(self, 'objectToArray'), $obj);
```

Provide an alternative solution for you (*encode the object to a json string, then decode it to an array*):

```
class Helpers {
     public static function objectToArray($obj) {
         return json_decode(json_encode($obj), true);
     }
}
```